# How can we use multi custom Mat Menu?

Tags: angular, angular-material

My application needs to use Multi custom menu. I can use this `@ViewChild(MatMenuTrigger) trigger: MatMenuTrigger;` code for a single mat menu. Please suggest me how can we achieve this for multi-menu and please find the example code for your reference.

**menu-example.html**

```html
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" (mouseenter)="someMethod()">Menu</button>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item >User</button>
  <button mat-menu-item >Cards</button>
  <button mat-menu-item >About</button>
</mat-menu>
```

**menu-example.ts**

```ts
import {Component, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';

import { MatMenuTrigger } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'menu-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'menu-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['menu-overview-example.css'],
})
export class MenuOverviewExample {
  @ViewChild(MatMenuTrigger) trigger: MatMenuTrigger;

  someMethod() {
    this.trigger.openMenu();
  }

}
```

**My question is**: how can use multi time for `@ViewChild(MatMenuTrigger) trigger: MatMenuTrigger;` and `this.trigger.openMenu();`

Will the below code work?

```ts
@ViewChild(MatMenuTrigger) trigger: MatMenuTrigger;
@ViewChild(MatMenuTrigger) trigger01: MatMenuTrigger;
someMethod() {
    this.trigger.openMenu();
}
anotherMethod() {
    this.trigger01.openMenu();
}
```

Comment: Any update on this ?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: After thinking for a while, it appears that you're looking for a way to make the nested menu automatically appear if the menu item is hovered over.

What you can try to do is to pass in the menu trigger's reference into the `showNestedMenu` method (as shown in the code below):

```html
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" (mouseenter)="showMenu()">Menu</button>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item [matMenuTriggerFor]="userMenu" (mouseenter)="showNestedMenu(nestedMenuTrigger)" #nestedMenuTrigger="matMenuTrigger">User</button>
  <mat-menu #userMenu="matMenu">
    <button mat-menu-item>John Tan</button>
    <button mat-menu-item>Logout</button>
  </mat-menu>
  <button mat-menu-item>Cards</button>
  <button mat-menu-item>About</button>
</mat-menu>
```

```ts
import { MatMenuTrigger } from '@angular/material';

// ...
export class MyComponent {
  showNestedMenu(menu: MatMenuTrigger) {
    menu.openMenu();
  }
}
```

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

If what you're asking for is a multi-menu/nested menu, this can be done by having another menu with a menu's trigger bound to the menu item:

```html
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" (mouseenter)="someMethod()">Menu</button>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item [matMenuTriggerFor]="userMenu">User</button>
  <mat-menu #userMenu="matMenu">
    <button mat-menu-item>John Tan</button>
    <button mat-menu-item>Logout</button>
  </mat-menu>
  <button mat-menu-item>Cards</button>
  <button mat-menu-item>About</button>
</mat-menu>
```

---

View the [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/menu/overview#nested-menu) for more info.

Comment: No, this is not i asked and you are telling about the nested menu which is already there in the link [link](https://material.angular.io/components/menu/overview#nested-menu) .
My question is How can we use the multi time for **MatMenuTrigger**.   Like below,
`@ViewChild(MatMenuTrigger) trigger: MatMenuTrigger;
@ViewChild(MatMenuTrigger) trigger01: MatMenuTrigger;
someMethod() {
    this.trigger.openMenu();
}
anotherMethod() {
    this.trigger01.openMenu();
}`

Comment: What did you mean by _time_? Your question makes **no sense**.